# How to Implement XEP-0012 using Jabber-net Library

Tags: c#, xmpp

I am making a Chat client in C# Windows Application Project.
I want to get the last status of a JID.  How can I Implement XEP-0012 (Last Activity of a JID) on Jabber-net .NET library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it myself...  and I am happy to share it. Let it be useful to people who wants this..

```
    public void RequestLastMessage(JID jabberid)
    {
        try
        {
            LastIQ iq = new LastIQ(jabberClient1.Document);
            iq.To = jabberid;

            iq.Type = jabber.protocol.client.IQType.get;
            jabberClient1.Tracker.BeginIQ(iq, LastMessage, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DebugLogger.LogRecord(ex.Message + " [ Function: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " Class: XMPPWrapper ]");
        }
    }

    private void LastMessage(object sender, jabber.protocol.client.IQ iq, object state)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((iq == null) || (iq.Type != jabber.protocol.client.IQType.result))
                return;
            Last ll = iq.Query as Last;
            if (iq.From != null && ll.Message != "")
                if (ApplicationVariables.GlobalContactForm != null) ApplicationVariables.GlobalContactForm.SetOfflineStatus(ll.Message, iq.From);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DebugLogger.LogRecord(ex.Message + " [ Function: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " Class: XMPPWrapper ]");
        }

    }
```

Comment: In the line `if (iq.From != null && ll.Message != "")` also check `ll != null`.  For extra credit, check with Caps to see if the other side implements this.  Also, *please* make sure you're not polling this periodically.  That would cause you to get rate limited quickly on many servers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you read the [Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/FAQ_Packets), then look at some of the existing code for some examples.  `jabber:iq:last` should be trivial from a protocol perspective, but many clients do not implement it anymore.